# When a method is wrapped by an AOP proxy, RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes() loses its headers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, kotlin, spring-aop

We have a weird issue with Spring AOP and Request context. We use some values from RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes() in our logic. A call within a proxied function can access our properties. However, when this function returns, request attributes, in particular request headers, are missing. We have been unable to ascertain why and are a bit at a loss.

Has somebody else come across this, or have any suggestion on how to fix this bug?

**Implementation details**

- SpringBoot version 2.2.1.RELEASE
- Kotlin version 1.3.60

We have implemented a SpringAop proxy to handle a cross cutting concern

```
@Aspect
@Component
class OurAspect {

  @AfterThrowing(value = "@annotation(annotation)", throwing = "ex", argNames = "ex,annotation")
  fun handleExceptions(joinPoint: JoinPoint, ex: RuntimeException, annotation: AopAnnotation): Any {
    throw SomeError()
  }
}
```

This is used in Service1

```
@Service
class Service1() {

  @AopAnnotation
  fun doStuff(): Any {
    // RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes has all requested properties here
    return // business logic
  }
}
```

In service 2, we call service 1

```
@Service
class Service2(private val service: Service1) {

  fun doStuff(): Any {
    val beforeRequest = getHeader() // this works
    val result = service.doStuff()
    val afterRequest = getHeader() // now missing
  }

  fun getHeader(): String {
    val request = (RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes() as ServletRequestAttributes).request
    return request.getAttribute("header_name")
  }
}
```